# How to make Bootstrap dropdown-menu full width of the content?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `dropdown-menu` in bootstrap with content as `pull-right` like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
<li><a href="">Link <span class="pull-right">123</span></li>
</ul>
```

How do I make it so that both the `Link` and the `123` are on the same line, no matter how wide it pulls the `dropdown-menu`?

Right now, it seems to push the `123` down to the next line if it becomes too wide.

I found a fix by adding `min-width: 200px;` for example, but it's not a nice solution because the menu might or might not contain a number count at all, so it leaves a blank space.

***Update:*** It seems that only in Firefox it's jumping to the next line, while Chrome shows it correctly.

Comment: Don't use `pull-right`?

Comment: How do I get it aligned on the right, then? :P

Comment: You need to show more of your code

Comment: Instead of using a space you can use a non breaking space `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answered my problem:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13876

It seems that the span pull-right must come BEFORE the text.